# Java/Hibernate comparator

Tags: java, hibernate, comparison, compare

Let's I have class

```
class Foo
```

and has two comparators for this class

```
class Comparator1 implements Comparator<Foo>  
class Comparator2 implements Comparator<Foo>
```

now I am using `TreeSet` of `Foo` objects in my class `Bar`.

```
class Bar  
{  
   private SortedSet<Foo> foos = new TreeSet(new Comparator1());  
}
```

in xml mapping

```
  <set name="foos"
     sort="com.package.Comparator2"
     fetch="subselect">
     <key column="column" not-null="true"/>
     <one-to-many class="Foo" />
  </set>
```

Which comparator will be used by hibernate after loading set from database, and which will be used after persist?
Can I use in local modification `Comparator1`, but for loading and saving `Comparator2`?

Comment: *which comparator will be used by hibernate after load set prof database* - Could you rephrase it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any collection will be rewritten while Hibernate loads entity from DB since it will need to use its own implementation of Set. If you created a brand new object and persisting it, then Comparator1 is still in use, because it's still your collection, it's not a Hibernate's proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by what I read [here](http://parasjain.net/2008/11/10/sorting-hibernate-set-using-a-comparator/) data in the database will be sorted using `Comparator2` and when you load data it will naturally use `Comparator2`.